# How can i disable web security in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a HTML5 project in my favorite editor, VS2012 :-). But I'm doing cross domain stuff and need to disable some security it in my favourite browser, chrome :-)

Until now I have a shortcut on my desktop to chrome where I've added the

```
--disable-web-security
```

So im writing code, saving, refreshing chrome (the page im working on) and writing alert() and console.log all over the js files to dump it because i cant set breakpoints.

But how can I set flags to the choosen emulator in Visual Studio?

Comment: How to disable web security in my project..iam working on phonegap..Iam getting security error while converting image url to base64 format in windows phone 8..